# Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Int' with an argument list of type '(DateComponents)'

Tags: swift

Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Int' with an argument list of type '(DateComponents)'

```
    var dayPicker:Int? = Int(sender.date.getDateTime().day)
    var monthPicker:Int? = Int(sender.date.getDateTime().month)
    var yearPicker:Int? = Int(sender.date.getDateTime().year)
    var hourPicker:Int? = Int(sender.date.getDateTime().hour)
    var minutePicker:Int? = Int(sender.date.getDateTime().minute)
    hourPicker! += 4
    print(hourPicker!)

    let dateCalendar = Date()

    var calendar = Calendar.current

    print(calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute], from: dateCalendar))

    var year = calendar.dateComponents([.year], from: dateCalendar)
    var month = calendar.dateComponents([.month], from: dateCalendar)
    var day = calendar.dateComponents([.day], from: dateCalendar)
    var hour = calendar.dateComponents([.hour], from: dateCalendar)
    var minute = calendar.dateComponents([.minute], from: dateCalendar)

    var resultDay = Int(dayPicker!) - Int(day)
```

ОШИБКА В ПОСЛЕДНЕЙ СТРОЧКЕ!

Comment: Ставите breakpoint на последнюю строчку и смотрите. В первую очередь смотрите на типы данных, т.к среда вам пишет, что не может провести конвертацию.

Answer (score 0):

```
var day = calendar.dateComponents([.day], from: dateCalendar)
```

Вот это вам вернет тип `DateComponents`, а не `Int`, как вы думаете. Собственно среда разработки вам об этом и сообщает.
Чтобы забрать день, как `Int` вам надо взять `day.day`